# Im unable to stop the input from taking place & play again loop middle of script

Tags: python, loops, input, pygame

I am making a custom version of hangman for a college assignment using python, but currently I'm having an issue with two parts to my code, its a game of hangman.

I have included the entire code below so that if anyone can answer they have the full information from the code.

The issues I'm having are that this part of the code is not ignoring the input before so it still lets you guess multiple letters.

```
        if len(guess) > 1:
            print("Ye can't be cheatin' now, ye be using up ya guesses.")
            failed += 1
```

The second issue I have is that once you win the game it doesn't ask if you want to play again properly (I have tried multiple methods to try to fix this including another `while` loop inside the `if` statement.

```
    if failed == 0:
        print("Ye be living for now")
        print("The word was: " + myword)
    print
```

---

...

```
while True:
```

...

```
        if failed == 0:
            print("Ye be living for now")
            print("The word was: " + myword)
        # Current Bug: Play again here, cannot use same line as end.
        print
        guess = input("guess a letter: ").lower()
        if len(guess) > 1:
            print("Ye can't be cheatin' now, ye be using up ya guesses.")
            failed += 1
            # Current Bug: still takes input into consideration when it shouldn't
        guesses += guess
```

...

```
    play_again = input("If you'd like to play again, please type 'yes' or 'y': ").lower()
    if play_again == "yes" or play_again == "y":
        continue
    else:
        play_again != "yes" or play_again != "y"
        break
```

Comment: I am just quickly looking through your code and I would suggest using a while loop for the looping if the game wants to be played again.

Comment: Yeah i tried to do that but it just said do you want to play again at each guess of the letter.

Comment: Don't include all code; create a [mcve] instead. It'll make it easier for us to determine the problem and also make the question more beneficial for other people. Also, you can remove the comments that are describing what the code does (like `# for every character in secret_word`, `#  if failed is equal to zero`, `# Create a while loop`, etc), because the code itself is saying the same. I know you want to write those to remind yourself but in a question they are excessive, making it much harder/energy consuming to read.

Comment: I have taken out the code that is likely not needed to be looked at and replaced it with ... to represent code between. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your problem of taking multiple letters as input

```
if len(guess) > 1:
    print("Ye can't be cheatin' now, ye be using up ya guesses.")
    failed += 1
    # Current Bug: still takes input into consideration when it shouldn't
else:
    guesses += guess
```

This will only add the input to guesses if its length is less than 1.

And if you want to ask the game to play again, after winning put your code in a while loop. Something like this:

```
play_again = 'y'
while(play_again == 'y' or play_again='yes'):
    win = False
    while(!win):
        <your code for game, set win = True after winning>
    play_again = input("Want to play again y or n: ").lower()
```

Edit: You can add failed along with win in the while loop as well.

Comment: Thanks this worked out for me (i may have had to change a few things with the loop but it worked out) :)